# Read multiple text files into a spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read multiple text files into a single spark data frame, I have used the following code for as single file:

```
df =spark.read.text('C:/User/Alex/Directory/Subdirectory/Filename.txt.pgp.decr')
df.count()
```

and I get the correct result, then I try and read in all of the files in that directory as follows:

```
df = spark.read.text('C:/User/Alex/Directory/Subdirectory/*')
df.count()
```

and the notebook just hangs and produces no result. I have also tried reading the data into a rdd using the sparkContext with textFile and wholeTextFiles, but also didn't come right, please can you help?

Comment: Do you have `.txt.pgp.decr` extension for all the files in the directory?

Comment: yes, all the files in the directory have that extension

Comment: I have modified all my files from '.txt.pgp.decr' to just '.txt' and I still get the same result, the code just hangs

Comment: And how many files do you have in that directory? How big are they? Any sub directories?